The projection of the polynomial onto U parallel to V
Prove that the space $P_3$ of polynomials of degree no higher than $3$ is the direct sum of subspaces $U$ and $V$ and find the projection of the polynomial $t^3$ onto $U$ parallel to $V$, where
\begin{align} 
U &= \{f(t) \in P_3 \mid f(1) = 0\}, \\[4pt]
V &= \{f(t) \in P_3 \mid 6f(0) = 6f'(0) = 3f''(0) = f'''(0)\}
\end{align}
First, I attempted to find the bases of these subspaces. Intuitively, $\dim(U)=3$. And the three basis vectors are: $t-1, (t-1)^2, (t-1)^3$. For subspace $V$, I've solved the system:
$$
6(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d) = 6(3ax^2+2bx+c) = 3(6ax+2b) = 6a
$$
with $x=0$ obtained $a=b=c=d$, so $\dim(V)=1$ and a basis vector is $t^3+t^2+t+1$. Since the sum of the dimensions of the subspaces $U$ and $V $equals the dimension of the entire space $P_3$:
$$
P_3 = U \oplus V.
$$
Next, I tried to find the projection. Let's take some vector $v = a(t^3+t^2+t+1) \in V$ and find the difference
$$
u = w-v = t^3-a(t^3+t^2+t+1) = (1-a)t^3-at^2-at-a, 
$$
where $w=t^3$ is the vector that we are projecting onto $U$. Next, I got stuck. Need to find the parameter $a$. I can't figure out how to find it. I’d be really thankful for any help.

Since $V$ is one dimensional, you can write $f(x)=g(x)+a(x^3+x^2+x+1)$ where $g(x)\in U$.    Evaluating at $1$ and using the fact that $g(1)=0$ by definition, we have $f(1)=4a$, so $a=f(1)/4$.  So to project to $V$, we map $f\mapsto \frac{f(1)}{4} (x^3+x^2+x+1)=P_V(f)$, and to project onto $W$ we get $P_W(f)=f-P_V(f)$.

Can I substitute 1 for t in $(1-a)t^3-at^2-at-a=0$, and get $a=0.25$? The projection will be equal to $0.75t^3-0.25t^2-0.25t-0.25$

@AliceP. Yes, if you plug in t=1 to that thing, you get 0.75-0.25-0.25-0.25=0, which shows that the result is in fact an element of $U$
